# If $a^2>b^2$ prove that $\int\limits_0^{\pi} \frac{dx}{(a+b\cos x)^3}=\frac{\pi (2a^2+b^2)}{2(a^2-b^2)^{5/2}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

**Problem:** If $a^2>b^2$ prove that $\int\limits_0^\pi \dfrac{dx}{(a+b\cos x)^3} = \dfrac{\pi (2a^2+b^2)}{2(a^2-b^2)^{5/2}}$.

**My effort:**
If we choose $$x=\tan\frac{\theta}{2}\Longrightarrow d\theta=\frac{2}{x^2+1} \, dx\;\;,\;\;\cos\theta=\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$$ then the integral becomes critical. What is the simplest way to solve?

Comment: I believe you meant to swap $x$ and $\theta$?

Comment: I would define $$I(t)=\int_0^\pi\frac{dx}{t+\cos x}$$ for $t>1$, find a formula for that and differentiate twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is well-known that
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{dx}{t+\cos x}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}$$
for $t>1$. Differentiating gives
$$-\int_0^\pi\frac{dx}{(t+\cos x)^2}=-\frac{\pi t}{(t^2-1)^{3/2}}.$$
Differentiating again gives
$$2\int_0^\pi\frac{dx}{(t+\cos x)^3}
%=-\frac{\pi(t^2-1)}{(t^2-1)^{5/2}}+\frac{3\pi t^2}{(t^2-1)^{5/2}}
=\frac{\pi(2t^2+1)}{(t^2-1)^{5/2}}.$$
Homogenising this gives your formula.

Comment: Nicely done (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482667/evaluating-int-02-pi-frac11a-cosx3-dx/4482702#4482702), making the problem more general, if $a>b$
$$I_n=\int\limits_0^{\pi} \frac{dx}{(a+b\cos x)^n}=\frac \pi {(a-b)^n }\,\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},n;1;\frac{2 b}{b-a}\right)$$ where appears the Gaussian hypergeometric function.

Using $b=c a$,
$$I_n=\frac \pi  {a^{n} (1-c)^{n}} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},n;1;-\frac{2 c}{1-c}\right)$$ with
$$(c+1) (n-1)\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},n;1;-\frac{2 c}{1-c}\right)=$$ $$(2 n-3) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},n-1;1;-\frac{2 c}{1-c}\right) -(1-c) (n-2) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},n-2;1;-\frac{2 c}{1-c}\right)$$

They also write
$$I_n=\pi\,a^{-n}\left(1-c^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}-n} \,\Big[1+c^2\ P_n\left(c\right)\Big]$$ and the first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n\left(c\right) \\
 1 & 0 \\
 2 & 0 \\
 3 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 4 & \frac{3}{2} \\
 5 & 3+\frac{3 }{8}c^2 \\
 6 & 5+\frac{15 }{8}c^2 \\
 7 & \frac{15}{2}+\frac{45 }{8}c^2+\frac{5 }{16}c^4 \\
 8 & \frac{21}{2}+\frac{105 }{8}c^2+\frac{35 }{16} c^4\\
 9 & 14+\frac{105 }{4}c^2+\frac{35 }{4}c^4+\frac{35 }{128}c^6   \\
 10 & 18+\frac{189 }{4}c^2+\frac{105 }{4}c^4+\frac{315 }{128}c^6 \\
 11 & \frac{45}{2}+\frac{315 }{4}c^2+\frac{525 }{8}c^4+\frac{1575
   }{128}c^6+\frac{63 }{256}c^8 \\
 12 & \frac{55}{2}+\frac{495 }{4}c^2+\frac{1155 }{8}c^4+\frac{5775
   }{128}c^6+\frac{693 }{256}c^8 \\
 13 & 33+\frac{1485 }{8}c^2+\frac{1155 }{4}c^4+\frac{17325 }{128}c^6+\frac{2079
   }{128}c^8+\frac{231 }{1024}c^{10}\\
 14 & 39+\frac{2145 }{8}c^2+\frac{2145 }{4}c^4+\frac{45045 }{128}c^6+\frac{9009
   }{128}c^8+\frac{3003 }{1024}c^{10}\\
 15 & \frac{91}{2}+\frac{3003 }{8}c^2+\frac{15015 }{16}c^4+\frac{105105
   }{128}c^6+\frac{63063 }{256}c^8+\frac{21021 }{1024}c^{10}+\frac{429
   }{2048}c^{12}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy is nice and correct.

If you want you can use some complex analysis.I do not know if this is simple.It depends on your knowledge.

Put $x=\frac{y}{2}$ so the endpoints will become $0,2 \pi$

Then :

Put $z=e^{it} ,dz=ie^{it}dt \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{zi}dz=dt$ and relate the trigonometric function with the exponentials with the appropriate identities and then  apply the residue theorem to the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

As [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482667/evaluating-int-02-pi-frac11a-cosx3-dx/4482702#4482702) is closed let me bring short answer here:

Having $I_n=\int\frac{dx}{(a+b\cos x)^n}$ partial integration gives
$$I_2(a^2-b^2) = aI_1-\frac{b\sin x}{a+b\cos x}$$
$$I_3 2(a^2-b^2) = 3aI_2 - I_1 -\frac{b\sin x}{a+b\cos x}$$
So $I_3$ can be represented as sum of constant member with $I_1$ plus function members.

Knowing, for $0\leqslant \varepsilon < 1$
$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{1+\varepsilon \cos x} = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-\varepsilon^2}}$$
we can obtain
$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{(a+b \cos x)^3}=\frac{\pi (2a^2+b^2)}{2(a^2-b^2)^{5/2}}$$